# jekyll highlight development vs production

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have found something odd.

Locally when run `jekyll serve --safe` and use highlight blocks

`{% highlight ruby %}`

it renders with a `<div class="highlight">` which is great and expected.

Oddly, when I push to gh-pages it uses a `<figure class="highlight">` and the default browser styles are significantly different.

how can i get them to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running an old version of Jekyll (probably 2.x).
This subtle change was made in Jekyll 3.0.x, and Github Page is currently using Jekyll 3.4.3 ([see gh pages dependencies here](https://pages.github.com/versions/)).

In order to stay in sync with github pages you can use bundler.

```
gem install bundler
```

Create a `Gemfile` at the root of your Jekyll files and add :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

Launch a `bundle` command, you libraries will be updated and your local version will run just as on Github pages.

Comment: added a `bundle update` to ^^ and it worked like a charm.